# Does it make sense to use a platform-agnostic HIG for desktop applcations?

Tags: desktop-application, guidelines, human-interface-guideline, cross-platform

I'm developing a stand-alone, cross-platform desktop app for Windows, Mac, and GNU/Linux. I've read these ([[1]](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/32935/guidelines-for-cross-platform-applications), [[2]](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/125509/should-a-cross-platform-desktop-application-use-a-uniform-ui-and-design-language)) questions and concluded that I'll have to cherry pick guidelines from all three  HIGs as the end-users span across the three platforms with Mac users > Windows Users >> GNU/Linux users. I was thinking about using a platform-agnostic HIG, but struggled to find modern ones. The most complete one I found was this archaic style guide for [WxWidgets from 2006](http://wyoguide.sourceforge.net/guidelines/content.html).

While being *very old*, a lot of the guidelines still hold true 15+ years later. Does it make sense to follow this guide or is that ridiculous?

Comment: Will this be a web app bundled in a package that can be installed?

Answer (score 0):

*The guidelines seem way too old to rely on them, even though they are written for cross-platform desktop applications.*

If there are no cross-platform human interface guidelines that are not that old, it seems reasonable to follow [Apple’s human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/guidelines/overview). They are considered one of the best in the field and for the most part, can be used as general guidelines not specific for Apple interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

A unified HIG would have made sense during the era that wxWidgets (and Java, for that matter) formed in: Windows 98, Mac OS 9, OS/2, Gnome 1 and the K Desktop Environment 1 all had a very similar look and feel to them - quite grey and quite boxy.

In the modern day, it doesn't quite hold up anymore unfortunately. Most annoyingly in the question of [which way round OK and Cancel goes](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/ok-cancel-on-left-right), but also more fundamentally in which input devices are available. Windows laptops for example somewhat frequently have the ability to switch mouse+keyboard for a tablet experience.

So your process of cherry-picking from all platform-relevant HIGs you're designing for is generally the right way to go, though I'd like to throw in that you'll need to be aware for platform-specific incompatible HIGs which probably mean the app should change depending on which version is used.